# Are Polymer and X-tag frontend frameworks compatible with a Content Management System ?

Tags: frameworks, polymer, content-management-system, portal, x-tag

I would like to use a Java EE portlet based portal builder as uPortal or Liferay to deploy a web portal.
Moreover, I have seen some new Frontend Frameworks (Polymer/X-tag) which seem to be really powerful and full of promises.

So I wanted to know if I will be able to deploy those frameworks to customize my portal ? Or if it is not compatible yet ?

Thanks in advance.

Axel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Components as a technology are completely agnostic to your server-side solution. So it will work the same as anything else that you would do in java land. I did a CMS with python backend and polymer components just fine.

Polymer does NOT support Server-Side rendering - but you would have to use nodejs for this to work in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't get it completely.

You said that Web Components technologies are independent from whatever backend technology is used. But in the mean time, Polymer does not support server-side rendering.

What does it mean ? And why nodejs ?

Axel

Comment: Web components are a way to extend DOM - you can create elements like your own custom <video-axel> tag - but the "insides" of the element are a black box with shadow dom. So from this point of view polymer does not implement anything to help you do server side rendering in react meaning of this word.

You can ofcourse do templates with your custom tags - and they will upgrade to full elements when the client js is loaded. So if your java portal outputs your shiny <foo-bar> element and the browser will load appropriate javascript to drive it it will transform into full component.